# Joomla monitor HTTP requests

Tags: logging, joomla

How can I monitor and log HTTP requests at a Joomla website? I want to determine the vulnerability that allows attacks. Please do not suggest ways to fix the vulnerabilities since this is another topic. I am specifically interested in monitoring every HTTP request the website receives.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about just inspecting your web server access logs / error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read how to create Plugin for Joomla

http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin_Developer_Overview

You need to create `system` plugin `onAfterRoute` event. This is after SEF is changed to GET variable.

I would go there through `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`